# ob_flush(), flush() not working from WAMP2 on Windows 7

Tags: php, buffer, flush

This snippet:

```
ob_start();

for($i=0;$i<70;$i++)
{
    echo 'printing...<br />';
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    usleep(300000);
}
```

From this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#85382

Isn't working on WAMP2 (PHP 5.3.0, Apache 2.2.11) installed on Windows 7, browsing from http://localhost with IE 8, FF 6.0.2 and Chrome 13.

None of them worked. All the 'printing...' lines are just output in one instant batch when the page finished processing.

**output_buffering** in php.ini is set to 'On'.

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: @fvu, thanks a lot for pointing that out. ;)

Comment: Which output buffer filters do you have enabled? Please check your config, e.g. if zlib is in action this can just happen.

Comment: Several reasons why flush fails are discussed on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php (eg interference with certain antivirus sw's, interference with zlib compression, ...).  Worth reading.

Comment: @hakre, do you mean this: zlib.output_compression = Off, if it is, it's 'Off'.

Comment: @fvu: Please add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several reasons why flush fails are discussed on [the ob_flush() documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) (eg interference with certain antivirus sw's, interference with zlib compression, ...). Worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to close the session:

```
echo 'printing...<br />';

session_write_close();

ob_flush();
flush();
```